# How to serialize slice without length using bincode?

Tags: serialization, rust

I'm using the bincode crate to write a structure into a file. The structure contains a slice with a fixed size. How can I force bincode to write only the slice's content without the slice's length?

```
#![allow(unstable)]
#![feature(custom_derive, plugin)]
#![plugin(serde_macros)]

extern crate serde;
extern crate bincode;

use std::fs::File;
use bincode::serde::serialize_into;
use bincode::SizeLimit;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Foo([u8; 16]);

fn main() {
    let data = Foo([0; 16]);
    let mut writer = File::create("test.bin").unwrap();
    serialize_into::<File, Foo>(&mut writer, &data, SizeLimit::Infinite).unwrap();
}
```

File 'test.bin' has 24 bytes size instead of 16.

I saw [related remark](http://tyoverby.com/bincode/serde/ser/trait.Serializer.html#method.serialize_bytes) in documentation of bincode, but I did not understand how to use it.

Comment: I *think* that I am already doing something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67168397/how-does-serde-bincode-serialize-byte-arrays but I do not understand how it is working.

Answer (score 3):

> a slice with a fixed size

`[u8; 16]` is **not** a *slice*. It is an *array* which may be coerced to a slice.

Anyway... I do not believe that you can. The important function appears to be [`Serializer::serialize_fixed_size_array`](http://tyoverby.com/bincode/serde/ser/trait.Serializer.html#method.serialize_fixed_size_array) which is not implemented by the [current serializer](https://github.com/TyOverby/bincode/blob/aa0f9804da3621259dd945992dea9116b8b49688/src/serde/writer.rs). That means it defaults to behaving the same as a slice.

Since slices do not have a length known at compile time, they must have their size written when serialized.

If no one else can provide a better suggestion, it's *possible* that the maintainer could find a way to make this happen. You may want to politely ask the maintainer for this feature or offer to help with the work.

---

Beyond that, it sounds like you are trying to make the bincode output fit a pre-existing format. That doesn't really make sense; bincode is its own format and had already made various choices and tradeoffs.

If you need to, you could implement your own encoder / decoder (either using serde or not). If you are concerned about file size, you can combine bincode with a compression step as well.

Comment: Yes, I need output defined in a specification. So, If it is so necessary, I will write own encoder.